# How to split data of 1 column in 3 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data is in given format-

```
Id      Date        Location
a123    6/6/2016    mmp
a123    6/7/2016    jpr
a123    6/8/2016    hjl
a123    6/9/2016    jhag
a678    6/10/2016   hjlwe
a678    6/11/2016   mkass
a980    6/7/2016    asdadf
a980    6/7/2016    lasdj
a980    6/7/2016    xswd
```

I want the same in given format-:

```
Id      Date 1      Location1   Date 2      Location 2  Date 3      Location 3
a123    6/6/2016    mmp         6/7/2016    jpr         6/8/2016    hjl
a678    6/10/2016   hjlwe       6/11/2016   mkass        
a980    6/7/2016    asdadf      6/7/2016    lasdj       6/7/2016
```

How to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT s.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.date END) as date_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.location END) as location_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.date END) as date_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.location END) as location_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 3 THEN s.date END) as date_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 3 THEN s.location END) as location_3
FROM(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.Date) as rnk
    FROM YourTable t) s
GROUP BY s.id
```

This can also be solved with `PIVOT` but I prefer to use conditional aggregation as long as the amount of the columns is limited .

If you need to add more levels, just follow the logic and replace `3` with `4` and so on..

Comment: This will not work if there are more than 3 columns. This needs to done using `Pivot` only

Comment: He specificly asked for 3 columns! Look at the example, `a123` has 4 dates, he wants the first 3! It does not matter what will happen with more then 3 columns. Oh , and by the way, it will work, just like `Pivot` @ChaosLegion .

Comment: @ChaosLegion, it can be done through dynamic crosstab/conditional aggregation. In fact, `PIVOT` is less efficient than the dynamic crosstab method. Read [**this**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/) article by Jeff Moden for more info.

Comment: @Felix: Liked the link. I correct my words back: "It can be done through Cross Tabs/Pivots better" :)

Comment: @sagi: No offense! But you ought to provide an extendable solution since this may affect someone's design in the future.

Comment: @ChaosLegion No, I'm not, I ought to provide a solution to the @OP , which is exactly my query and as Felix said it's more efficient then `Pivot` . Can you explain the downvote for a correct answer?

Comment: Explanation of downvote is simple: I want a better answer available to be considered more than this one. No personal vendetta

Comment: This is the best solution for this perticular problem, so in other word, you want to misguide people as to your opinion . @ChaosLegion

Comment: @ChaosLegion use downvote for answers that are not useful, as the hover text says. This clearly is a useful answer, which became the basis of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can make it with `PIVOT` (if number of columns can change dynamically you must use dynamic SQL):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('a123',    '6/6/2016',    'mmp'),
('a123',    '6/7/2016',    'jpr'),
('a123',    '6/8/2016',    'hjl'),
('a123',    '6/9/2016',   'jhag'),
('a678',    '6/10/2016',   'hjlwe'),
('a678',    '6/11/2016',   'mkass'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'asdadf'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'lasdj'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'xswd')
) as t(Id, [Date], [Location])
)

SELECT  p1.Id,
        p1.[Date1],
        p2.[Location1],
        p1.[Date2],
        p2.[Location2],
        p1.[Date3],
        p2.[Location3],
        p1.[Date4],
        p2.[Location4]
FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  Id, 
                [Date], 
                'Date' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) as rn
        fROM cte
        ) AS D
    PIVOT (
    MAX([Date]) for  RN in ([Date1],[Date2],[Date3],[Date4])
    ) as pvt
    ) as p1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  Id, 
                [Location], 
                'Location' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) as rn
        fROM cte
        ) AS D
    PIVOT (
    MAX([Location]) for  RN in ([Location1],[Location2],[Location3],[Location4])
    ) as pvt
    ) as p2
    ON p1.Id = p2.Id
```

Output:

```
Id   Date1     Location1 Date2     Location2 Date3     Location3 Date4     Location4
---- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
a123 6/6/2016  mmp       6/7/2016  jpr       6/8/2016  hjl       6/9/2016  jhag
a678 6/10/2016 hjlwe     6/11/2016 mkass     NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL
a980 6/7/2016  lasdj     6/7/2016  xswd      6/7/2016  asdadf    NULL      NULL
```

**EDIT**

With dynamic SQL (same output):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    Id nvarchar(10),  
    [Date] date, 
    [Location] nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('a123',    '6/6/2016',    'mmp'),
('a123',    '6/7/2016',    'jpr'),
('a123',    '6/8/2016',    'hjl'),
('a123',    '6/9/2016',   'jhag'),
('a678',    '6/10/2016',   'hjlwe'),
('a678',    '6/11/2016',   'mkass'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'asdadf'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'lasdj'),
('a980',    '6/7/2016',    'xswd')

DECLARE @locs nvarchar(max), 
        @dates nvarchar(max), 
        @cols nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @locs = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME('Location' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)))
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

SELECT @dates = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME('Date' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)))
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME('Date' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10))) + 
                    ',' + QUOTENAME('Location' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)))
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')


SELECT @sql ='
SELECT  p1.Id,
        '+@cols+'
FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  Id, 
                [Date], 
                ''Date'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) as rn
        fROM #temp
        ) AS D
    PIVOT (
    MAX([Date]) for  RN in ('+@dates+')
    ) as pvt
    ) as p1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  Id, 
                [Location], 
                ''Location'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) AS NVARCHAR(10)) as rn
        fROM #temp
        ) AS D
    PIVOT (
    MAX([Location]) for  RN in ('+@locs+')
    ) as pvt
    ) as p2
    ON p1.Id = p2.Id'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many columns you have, you can use a dynamic version of [sagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37651247/2203084). Here is one using a [**dynamic crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    t.id' + CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql = @sql + 
(SELECT
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' THEN t.Date END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Date' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10))) + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' THEN t.Location END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Location' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10))) + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM tbl
) t
ORDER BY rn
FOR XML PATH(''));

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) AS rn
    FROM tbl
) t
GROUP BY t.Id;';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/496204)</kbd>

Comment: This is the correct answer for an unknown number of columns. +1